# Calculate the derivative of a function and the slope of the tangent line at a given point

Tags: calculus

I know how to get this derivative thing, but I don't understand what is meant by the slope at a given point.

For exemple, for $f(x)=-2/x$ the derivative is $f'(x)=2/x^2$

Now how do I get this slope thing at $c=-1$?

Comment: What does $f'(a)$ mean for some point x=a? By slope, they mean the slope of the tangent line to a given point.

Comment: I'm really slow with maths. Do I only need to find the derivative then calculate a $y$ value by applying this derivative function to the given $x$ value. And then the slope will be $y/x$? Am I on the right path or completely lost?

Comment: The slope of the tangent at a point of the curve is the value of the derivative at this point. Since you have the derivative, then the slope is ... ?

Comment: Alright, no problem.  Recall that the slope of a line is the change in $y$ over the change in $x$, right?
For any point on a function $f(x)$ at which the derivative can be taken (e.g. you can't find $f'(0)$ for $f(x)=2/x$ since $f(0)$ is not defined), the tangent line to that point is the line that touches that point on $f$ once without intersecting $f$.  Then, when we talk about the "slope" of $f$ at a point, we're talking about the slope of the tangent line to that point, and the derivative of $f$ evaluated at the point is precisely that slope.

Comment: Didn't quite get it. It's the line that touches that point coming from where? Ins't it possible there are other lines touching that point without intersecting $f$?

Comment: Hate to complicate things, but technically, it can even cross the curve,  though for many nice functions it doesn't. You can think of the tangent line as the line that a very tiny nearsighted bug will think it is sitting on if it is sitting on the curve at $x=1$.

Comment: Ok. If the exercises ask for the "slope of the tangent line", "the angular coefficient of the tangent line", "the variation rate of $f(x)$ for $x=number$" and "the variation rate $dx/dy$ in a given point" is it all exactly the same thing? Just find the derivative then use it for the $x$ coordinate of the given point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative gives you the slope at a point.  For a given curve, if a tangent line exists, there is one unique derivative value, which is the slope at a point.  If it helps, recall that the definition of derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
Now what that intuitively is without the limit is the slope of the line between points $x$ and $x+h$.  If we let $h\rightarrow0$, that is just the slope at the point $x$.  There is more to it, and it can be hard to believe at first, but just trust us for now :)

So in your case, $f(x)=\frac{-2}{x}$ so you correctly calculated $f'(x)=\frac{2}{x^2}$.  This gives you the slope at any point $x$ where $f'(x)$ is defined.  Now go ahead and plug $x=-1$ in to get
$$
f'(-1)=\frac{2}{(-1)^2}=2
$$

This video might also help you out
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAof9Ld5sOg